# What non-IT career paths can IT professionals transfer their skills to?

Tags: career-development, career-switch

I spent so much time of my life with computers that I am starting to get fed up with them. I dread the idea of having to work on a computer for the rest of my life.

You know that video of an employee flipping out and smashing his computer on the floor? That's what I will look like if I continue this life...

What kind of career paths, areas, professions, etc. can use the skills I have (except for the computer use), e.g. analytical, etc. but without having to use a computer most of the time?

I really want to get away from IT, as a whole.

Comment: Have you read the [scope](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of what is on topic?

Comment: You don't want to work with computers, but you want to work in areas where your IT skills will help? That doesn't sound very logical.

Comment: My suggestion would be to consider becoming someone that works in 3rd world countries where computers aren't common yet.  Most jobs these days will involve using a computer even if you are a salesmen, cashier or executive as most people like using technology to some degree.

Comment: IT skills is not just the computer right? I mean, analytical skills, organization, etc.

I also don't mean to exclude computers 100% from my life, but just not make them the centre of my life.
e.g. I could imagine myself working as a TV presenter who sometimes needs to check the computer for information, etc.

Comment: @technophobia Oh I see. Yes, sometimes I get this feeling too. I know hoy you feel.

Comment: Similar to JB King's comment, there are many 3rd world volunteer programs to teach IT or even develop software.  You may find that getting involved in something more worthwhile in a foreign country cleans the palate for your main skill, plus can be a great talking point for a new job when you come back.

Answer (score 5):

I sometimes feel the same thing that you are feeling. I think what you want is not to get away from IT, but to get away from an office job where your day-to-day is on a desk, possibly bound by cubicle walls.

It depends on what your other analytical skills are. You'll have a broader range of possibilities if you got "people skills". I don't mean this as in suggesting you become a manager; I mean as, for example, you could be:

- A consultant to a firm. Propose plans for IT, which way to go with technology, which products and services to buy. You don't have to directly implement;
- A professor in a college. You could teach any number of subjects to undergraduates, like databases, programming, project management, IT governance etc. You may have to do some practical IT work here and there, but the bulk of your work will be preparing and giving lessons and exams.

If you tell us what other skills you have besides IT, we can suggest more things. For example, if you are willing to get a degree on law and become a lawyer, there is big money to be made working for companies that have a lot of intelectual property. This area requires a very strong IT background. I know two people who work with that and find it a very rewarding area, not only in a financial sense but also in a personal one.

Comment: Or work at a library, or in an elementary school, or for a non-profit.